# Multiple, dependent API calls in try/catch block? (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, try-catch, refactoring

I am wondering how to best handle multiple, dependent API calls in nodejs with a try catch block. Say I need to send a request, wait for the response, then use the response in a subsequent API request to a different server and so on. I initially tried to separate these into  several try/catch blocks, but then realised that if I am dependent on the response, I cannot really split subsequent requests apart.

Here is an example of what I mean:

```
try {
      const token = await getAuth0Token();
      const userExistsInAuth0 = await doesUserExist({
        email,
        token
      });

      if (!userExistsInAuth0) {
        return res.status(500).json({
          //...
        });
      }

      // Create User
      let createUserStatus = await createUser({
         //....
      });

      if (createUserStatus == 'error') {
        return res.status(200).json({
            //...
        });
      }

      const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        //...
      });

      return res.status(200).json({ //Success
         //...
      });
    } catch (error) {    
      return res.status(500).json({ //Error
         //...
      });
    }
```

Is this a recommended way to go about this? I am worried it will very soon get very messy, but I don't understand how I could break things apart.

Comment: seems clean and readable to me. what are you worried about?

Comment: @malong11 thank you! I guess being a beginner, I am a bit more worried than I should be maybe to miss something or do something the wrong way, esp. since this is payment and each step depends on the success of the previous one etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define custom Error-classes and throw instances of these classes in your services. Then you handle those errors inside your already existing catch block. E.g:

```
class UserNotFound extends Error { ... }
class CreateUserError extends Error { ... }
// etc.
```

Then in your catch block you can use `instanceof` to determine the error:

```
try {
      const token = await getAuth0Token();
      // doesUserExist now throws an UserNotFound error if the user does not exist yet
      const userExistsInAuth0 = await doesUserExist({
        email,
        token
      });     

      // Create User
      let createUserStatus = await createUser({
         //....
      });     

      const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        //...
      });

      return res.status(200).json({ //Success
         //...
      });
    } catch (error) {  
      if (error instance of UserNotFound) { // handle UserNotFound error 
      } else if(error instance of CreateUserError) { // handle CreateUserError error
      } else {
        // handle any unhandled error
        return res.status(500).json({ //Error
         //...
       });
      }
    }
```